# Ambiguity of "bag down for a better ride"

Tags: verbs, nouns, ambiguity

Today I saw a sign on the train that said

> **Bag** down for a better ride.

There was an accompanying picture of someone carrying a large bag on his back, possibly causing inconvenience to others:

[image: Bag Down for a Better Ride]

Initially, I thought it meant *put less things in your bag*, with *bag* used as a verb in the sign. Later on, I realised it meant *put down your bag*, with *bag* used as a noun instead. Can it really mean either thing?

Comment: 'Chin up' is an accepted and well known shortened form of 'Keep your chin up'. I can't find 'Bag down' used in stand-alone fashion, and certainly wouldn't use it myself. The thrust of the message is certainly 'Don't cause others / yourself inconvenience', but the particular meaning of a deletion is usually going to be uncertain. Perhaps here it's meant to be.

Comment: I guess the picture is intended to make it clear. I'm not sure why you would interpret _down_ to mean _less_. Obviously it would be clearer if it said "put your bag down", but short slogans are more pithy and fit on signs more easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it would mean either, had it not carried a picture with it. But with the picture in it, it is just so straight forward that putting your bag down makes commuting easier and definitely considerate too for fellow passengers.